# django rest upload multiple images

Tags: django, image, django-rest-framework

I'm working on an e-commerce API with Django rest framework
so I want when the user adds a new product he can upload multiple images
how can I do that with rest framework?
here are my models, views, serializer

my models.py

```
    class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Products', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    class ProductImages(models.Model):
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
     images = models.FileField(upload_to='API/images',max_length=100,null=True)
```

my serializer

```
class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImages
        fields = '__all__'
class Productserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    images= ProductImageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id','title','price','description','whatfor','categories','size','rooms','Location','Lat','Long','owner_id','images')
        extra_kwargs = {"user":{"read_only":True}}
        
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs['owner'] = self.context.get("request").user
        return attrs
```

my views

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Productserializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
    search_fields = ['title', 'description']
    ordering_fields = ['price', 'last_update']
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'request': self.request}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to implement multiple upload, you need to set the additional field for uploading in the `ProductSerializer`.

```
class Productserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    images= ProductImageSerializer(many=True, read_only = True)
    uploaded_images = serializers.ListField(
        child = serializers.FileFiled(max_length = 1000000, allow_empty_file = False, use_url = False)
        write_only = True
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', ...,'images', 'uploaded_images', ) # add the field
        extra_kwargs = {"user":{"read_only":True}}
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        uploaded_data = validated_data.pop('uploaded_images')
        new_product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for uploaded_item in uploaded_data:
            new_product_image = ProductImages.objects.create(product = new_product, images = uploaded_item)
        return new_product
```

And in the frontend, you need to change the key `images` into `uploaded_images`.
For example, like the following.

```
const formData = new FormData();
event.target.files.forEach((image) => {
    formData.append('uploaded_images', image);
});
```

Comment: u mean return new_product_image right?
but i got an error "Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use images.set() instead."

Comment: What do you mean to "return new_product_image"?

Comment: And is the `images` field `FileField` in the `ProductImages` model ?

Comment: yes the images in the productimages is filefield
u said 
for uploaded_item in uploaded_data:
            new_product_image = ProductImages.objects.create(product = new_product, images = uploaded_item)
        return new_product
but there is no new_product_image

Comment: Yeah, `new_product_image` is defined but not used. I think `new_product_image=`  can be omitted. Just put the code `ProductImage.object.create(...)` without assignment.

Comment: But you should return `new_product` object.

Comment: like this right?
https://pastebin.com/PSPQuKdK
i got the same error 
Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use images.set() instead.

Comment: You missed the `read_only = True` in line `images= ProductImageSerializer(many=True)`

Comment: `images` field is for reading and `uploaded_images` field is for writing.

Comment: yeah its working now after i changed the related_name in of the product in the productimage field to upload_images
but the problem is now I can send multiple images but I cant see them in the serializer response? i get the title,price... but no images
how can I do that?

Comment: Now you shouldn't change `related_name` field. Why did you change it?

Comment: @Metalgear I am using your code suggestion to also try and upload multiple images to a post but for this line uploaded_data = validated_data.pop('uploaded_images') I am getting a KeyError 'uploaded_images' Any idea why? My code looks exactly like yours